# Getting PHP Version for Currently Running Version

Tags: php, bash, grep

I have just built 3 different versions of PHP from source on an Ubuntu server (alongside NGINX and MySQL 5.7). I am looking for a way to run `php --ini` for the currently running version. I know I have to add the location to the file `PATH` in `.bashrc` so I don't have to add the full path.

I have added this to my `.bashrc` which allows me to get the currently running PHP version, which then allows me to run the command:

```
# parallels@ubuntu:~$ ps aux | grep php
# root      6948  0.0  0.2 153724  4620 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/opt/php-7.0.0/etc/php-fpm.conf)

PHP_VERSION=$(ps aux | grep -o php-[[:digit:]].[[:digit:]].[[:digit:]])
export PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/$PHP_VERSION/bin:/sbin"
```

It works, but I am a bash novice and I'm thinking their might be a different way to do it. Would I be correct?

Comment: The "pro" version would not be relying on PHP being running at login, and also actually checking that your command produced the expected results before cramming it into your `$PATH`.

Comment: @anubhava I need `/opt/<php-version>/bin` in my `PATH` so I can run `php --ini`. If it's not there, it says it's not installed and advised me on how to install it. It is installed though, as I built from source.

Answer (score 8):

```
PHP_VERSION=$(php -v | tail -r | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -c 1-3)
cd /usr/local/etc/php/$PHP_VERSION/
# cd /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/
```

Comment: Heya, I don't follow what `tail -r` does, atleast on ubuntu 18 it's not in the man page; Closest I see is --retry, any advice?

Comment: I think he was trying to reverse. If you use `tac` instead of `tail -r` it works.

Comment: how about `head -n 1`

Answer (score 8):

This command works while running in PHP

```
<?php
    echo PHP_VERSION;
```

You can get it in bash, like

```
PHP_VERSION=$(php -r "echo PHP_VERSION;")
```

Here is [all of PHP Predefined Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)

Comment: you can get `PHP_MAJOR_VERSION` or `PHP_MINOR_VERSION` too

Answer (score 7):

I got it to work with the following commands:

```
# Full version
php -v | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2

# Major.Minor version
php -v | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -f1-2 -d"."
```

Comment: # Full version for me returned "7.3.28-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1" So, I modified it slightly to: `php -v | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -f1 -d"-"` which returns 7.3.28 on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2):

should be able to get it done with awk.

`php -v | awk 'NR<=1{ print $2 }'`

print the second column from the first row of input.